# How to generically authorize or validate a JSON rest request based on the authenticated user and an attribute of the requestbody

Tags: spring, rest, basic-authentication, validation

My current Spring3 REST JSON api is authenticated with the default InMemory properties file/basic-authentication authentication manager.  That has worked fine thus far, but I need to further validate that an incoming request is allowed to be made for that user.  The Role concept seems to work fine as a gateway for entry to a particular controller's url, but it doesn't go far enough to validate that the user is permitted to ask for the data being requested.

In my app, each B2B partner that will be making requests to the API is assigned an applicationId.  That partner user account is only allowed to make requests for that applicationId.  The applicationId is passed as an attribute of the RequestBody POJO for all the POST API messages. I would like to decline requests that are made for improper applicationIds.

How can I validate that the authenticated user is making a permitted request?

I've started down the path of creating a custom AuthenticationProvider, but I don't know how to get access to the applicationId within the RequestBody bean that hadn't been marshalled into the java bean yet.

Perhaps a custom AuthenticationProvider isn’t the right solution, and a request validator of some sort is needed.  If so, how would the validator on the appId attribute get access to the Principal (authenticated user object)

With any solution, I would like it be invisible to the controller, so that requests that do make it to the controller are permitted ones.  Also, ideally,  the solution should not depend on an engineer to remember some annotation to make the logic work.

Thanks in advance,
JasonV

EDIT 1: By implementing an InitBinder in the controller, and using the @Valid annotation on the RequestBody I was able to validate a request.  However, this is not the Droids (er I mean solution) I'm looking for. I need to find a more generic way to handle it without all those Binders and annotations; too much to remember and spread around the application over dozens of request controllers, and it will be forgotten in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way to implement this is using @PreAuthorize.

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('USER') and authentication.principal.approvedAppId == #dto.applicationId")
@RequestMapping...
public ... someMethod(@RequestBody Dto dto, ...)
```

If you're worried about the repetition of the SpEL, define a new annotation like @PreAuthorizeUser and set the @PreAuthorize as a meta-annotation on it.

Comment: very nice - I wasn't aware of the dot syntax available in the aspects.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to utilize an aspect to solve the problem generically.

I would still like to see if it is possible to do the following:
Get a marshalled RequestBody from the request object in the context of an AuthenticationProvider.

Here is the aspect code for future help to others.

```
@Pointcut("within(@org.springframework.stereotype.Controller *)")
public void controllerBean() {
}

@Pointcut(
        "execution(org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity *(.., @org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody (*),..))")
public void methodPointcut() {
}

@Around("controllerBean() && methodPointcut()")
public Object beforeMethodInControllerClass(ProceedingJoinPoint jp) throws Throwable {

        Object[] args = jp.getArgs();
        long requestAppId = Long.parseLong(BeanUtils.getProperty(args[0], "applicationId"));

        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        User principal = (User) auth.getPrincipal();
        String username = principal.getUsername();
        long[] approvedAppIds = getApprovedAppIdsForUsername(username);

        for (long approvedAppId : approvedAppIds) {
            if (approvedAppId == requestAppId) {
                isAllowedAccess = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (isAllowedAccess) {
            return jp.proceed(args);
        } else {
            LOGGER.warn("There was an attempt by a user to access an appId they are not approved to access: username="+username+", attempted appId="+requestAppId);
            return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
        }
}
```